# Sequalize Typescript - Can't access static member with schema()

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

I have model which are stored in separate schema on postgres so I tried to call schema method before accessing other method like below,

> Organization.schema("test").findAll();

but Typescript compiler throws error

> Property 'findAll' is a static member of type 'Model'

but actually it worked and I able to access the model from that specific schema, really not sure how to get rid of this error from compiler and lint, I am not much fluent over typescript, may be this is related to typescript.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @GCM I actually fixed and made pull request and the commit also merged
https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/issues/494